# Enlarging embark location after embark?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there any way to make my embark location larger?  Or some way to rembark without getting different dwarves?  I saved my skills/items to a profile, but I want the same dwarves because I spent a huge amount of time matching skills with their attributes/preferences.

I thought the 4x4 square I chose was just the little meeting spot my wagon and dwarves would gather.  Now I see that it actually is the edge of my playable area.

I had planned to dig into a mountain but I embarked in the forest right next to it.  So I am really missing the giant cliffs I had planned to build into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible as of the latest verstion of Dwarf Fortress (31.25)

You are able to enlarge your embark location pre-embark, but there is no way to guarantee the same dwarves on a reembark (and indeed, I believe Dwarves are spawned from thin air (rather than taken from historical dwarves).

Do note that lesser computers are likely to struggle with embarks greater than 4 x 4.

Comment: What happens when I abandon then reembark at the same location(with larger size)? will I see remnants of the previous mining/construction?

Comment: Rembarking, off the top of my head, kills all mud in the caverns, scatters all the items on site at the time of your previous abandonment, and kills all non-dwarf animals (with their rotting corpses strewn about the same place. All mining / construction will remain unaltered (i.e., it will be how it was when they abandoned)